# API to read, write and manipulate msword files

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to write some java code to read, write, edit and do other things with sets of Microsoft Word files (different Word versions). What is the best API for this, and how do I get started?
P.S. I searched StackOverflow and found that this question has been asked before, but several years ago. I would like to know the best available API today. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Jim, As I said, what I have done is search Stackoverflow. There are a few recommendations there, but these are from 2014 or earlier. I am looking for a new API. What more do you want me to describe?

Comment: It's not a question of describing anything.  Your question is off-topic for this site.  Ask on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out apache POI : https://poi.apache.org/

As quoted on their website.. "*Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents*"

Personally I have only used this for EXCEL spreadsheet manipulation, but it does support word documents as well...

The best part is it's open source and completely free!